# Flutter bottomSheet with input in a column and an attachment icon on the bottom, keyboard hides the icon when active

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

I am showing a bottom sheet with `showModalBottomSheet` like so:

```
showModalBottomSheet(
    isScrollControlled: true,
    context: context,
    backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
    builder: (BuildContext context) {
      return StatefulBuilder(
        builder: (BuildContext context, StateSetter setState) {
          return Container(
            height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * .90,
            width: double.infinity,
            child: Column(
              children: [
                Expanded(
                  child: PostCreate(isImageType: isImageType)
                ),
                Padding(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(20, 0, 0, 20),
                  child: Align(
                    alignment: Alignment.bottomLeft,
                    child: IconButton(
                      onPressed: () {
                        setState(() {
                          isImageType = true;
                        });
                      },
                      icon: Icon(Icons.attach_file_rounded),
                    )
                  ),
                )
              ],
            ),
          );
        }
      );
    }
  );
```

The `PostCreate` widget contains a column with a * form (single input) and a section for adding the images. When the keyboard is not visible the `attach_file_rounded` Icon is where you would expect (bottom left), but when the input is focused and the keyboard is visible, the icon is hidden behind the keyboard. I'm not concerned about the code in `PostCreate` because if I change it to just a form/input in Expanded:

```
Expanded(
  child: Form(
    child: TextFormField(
      autofocus: true,
    ) 
  )
)
```

I have the same exact problem. What's the way for me to align something on the bottom left of a bottom sheet that will dynamically sit above the keyboard when it is active? Another thing to note, is that I do want the `PostCreate` widget to expand, allowing room for certain things (like the attach_file icon) on the bottom of the sheet. That is all working as expected, I just need it to adjust with the keyboard.

Answer (score 0):

I figured this out by adding `padding: MediaQuery.of(context).viewInsets,` to the Padding widget around the Align/IconButton widgets.

```
Padding(
  padding: MediaQuery.of(context).viewInsets,
  child: Align(
    alignment: Alignment.bottomLeft,
    child: IconButton(
      onPressed: () {
        setState(() {
          isImageType = true;
        });
      },
      icon: Icon(Icons.attach_file_rounded),
    )
  ),
)
```